# Новая роль для пользователей, имеющих права создания записей только в определенных рубриках WordPress - как?

Tags: wordpress, usercontrol, wp-plugin, role

Есть такая задача для WordPress:

Создать новую роль для пользователей и чтобы пользователи этой роли имели права подобно роли Редактор, но могли создавать/редактировать/удалять записи только лишь в определенных рубриках WordPress.

Может кто-нибудь подскажет готовое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как получилось всё это реализовать при помощи всего двух плагинов WordPress:

> - Restrict Author Posting
> - User Role Editor